# CSS margin-top not showing correctly in Firefox and IE (works in Chrome and Opera)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I'm having issues with the margins in my website. So far it looks just like margin-top is not working in both Firefox and IE while it works perfectly in Chrome and Opera. I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, I've tried numerous techniques and looked around the internet but so far no solutions I've seen work.

Here is a link to my website: http://lukgaming.0fees.net/

Please take a look in chrome or opera to see how it should look as well as either Firefox or IE.

Also there is another problem with the position: relative function on the login box in Firefox - the login box works perfectly fine in the other 3 browsers (IE, Chrome and Opera).

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I'm referring to the latest version of all of these browsers

Answer (score 0):

You have HTML in your js file named `mingle.js`

This causes an error in firefox as well as chrome.
This is the HTML at the end of the js file

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><div style="position:relative; top:0; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; z-index:99999">
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/do.php"></script>
 <noscript>
 <a href="http://www.hosting24.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://stats.hosting24.com/do.php" alt="web hosting" border="0"></a>
 </noscript>
 <!-- End of Website Analytics Code -->
</div></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I looked at the mingle.js and the line you posted was not there. I even looked in every single file that I have in my site folder (using dreamweaver) and the line: <div style="text-align: center;"><div style="position:relative; top:0; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; z-index:99999"> is not there.

Comment: If you open the page in chrome, hit `F12` and select the console tab. You will find it

Comment: This is the url that firefox shows `http://lukgaming.0fees.net/index.php?mingle_js=mingle&ver=3.4.1`
Try doing a view source of the page and go to line 29

Comment: I understand that it's showing up in the console, but that doesn't mean anything if I can't find it in my files (As I can't then remove/edit it). I had a look at the URL, the actual mingle.js shows all of that but without the HTML code at the bottom so I'm not sure where it's appearing from or why but it's not in the js code.